# ValueError: Input 0 of layer "model" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 41671, 43), found shape=(None, 43)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, transformer-model

I am modifying the "Timeseries classification with a Transformer model" found [here](https://keras.io/examples/timeseries/timeseries_transformer_classification/), with a dataset that has 41671 rows and 43 columns. Here is the code that I am using:

```
# Model 5: Time-Series Transformer for Classification
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from keras import layers
import numpy as np

tickers = ['AAPL', 'GOOG', 'MSFT', 'INTC', 'AMZN']

def transformer_encoder(inputs, head_size, num_heads, ff_dim, dropout=0):
    x = layers.LayerNormalization(epsilon=1e-6)(inputs)
    x = layers.MultiHeadAttention(
        key_dim=head_size, num_heads=num_heads, dropout=dropout
    )(x, x)
    x = layers.Dropout(dropout)(x)
    res = x + inputs

    # Feed Forward Part
    x = layers.LayerNormalization(epsilon=1e-6)(res)
    x = layers.Conv1D(filters=ff_dim, kernel_size=1, activation="relu")(x)
    x = layers.Dropout(dropout)(x)
    x = layers.Conv1D(filters=inputs.shape[-1], kernel_size=1)(x)
    return x + res

def build_model(
    input_shape,
    head_size,
    num_heads,
    ff_dim,
    num_transformer_blocks,
    mlp_units,
    dropout=0,
    mlp_dropout=0,
):
    inputs = keras.Input(shape=input_shape)
    print(inputs.shape)
    x = inputs
    for _ in range(num_transformer_blocks):
        x = transformer_encoder(x, head_size, num_heads, ff_dim, dropout)
        print(x.shape)

    x = layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D(data_format="channels_first")(x)
    print(x.shape)
    for dim in mlp_units:
        x = layers.Dense(dim, activation="relu")(x)
        print(x.shape)
        x = layers.Dropout(mlp_dropout)(x)
        print(x.shape)
    outputs = layers.Dense(1, activation="softmax")(x)
    print(outputs.shape)
    return keras.Model(inputs, outputs)

# Model Training
for i in range(len(tickers)):
    train_tickers = tickers.copy()
    train_tickers.pop(i)
    print(train_tickers)
    df_train = pd.DataFrame()
    for train_ticker in train_tickers:
        df = pd.read_csv(f"Spoofing-Injected DataFrames/{train_ticker}_segmentsummary_spoofed_bidside_{FACTOR}_{INTERVAL_START}_{INTERVAL_END}.csv", index_col=0)
        df_train = pd.concat([df_train, df], axis=0)
    X_train = df_train.drop("Classification", axis=1)
    y_train = df_train["Classification"]
    df_valid = pd.read_csv(f"Spoofing-Injected DataFrames/{tickers[i]}_segmentsummary_spoofed_bidside_{FACTOR}_{INTERVAL_START}_{INTERVAL_END}.csv", index_col=0)
    X_valid = df_valid.drop("Classification", axis=1)
    y_valid = df_valid["Classification"]
    # batch_size = None
    model5 = build_model(
        input_shape=X_train.shape,
        head_size=256,
        num_heads=4,
        ff_dim=4,
        num_transformer_blocks=4,
        mlp_units=[128],
        mlp_dropout=0.4,
        dropout=0.25
    )

    model5.compile(
        loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
        optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-4),
        metrics=['sparse_categorical_accuracy']
    )

    model5.summary()

    callbacks = [keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(patience=10, restore_best_weights=True)]
    history = model5.fit(
        X_train,
        y_train,
        validation_split=0.2,
        epochs=200,
        batch_size=64,
        callbacks=callbacks,
        verbose=0
    )

    model.evaluate(X_valid, y_valid, verbose=1)
    history_df = pd.DataFrame(history.history)
    # Start the plot at epoch 5
    history_df.loc[5:, ['loss', 'val_loss']].plot()
    history_df.loc[5:, ['binary_accuracy', 'val_binary_accuracy']].plot()

    print(("Best Validation Loss: {:0.4f}" +\
        "\nBest Validation Accuracy: {:0.4f}")\
        .format(history_df['val_loss'].min(), 
                history_df['val_binary_accuracy'].max()))
```

But I am receiving the error that is in the title. It is detecting an input shape of (None, 43) when it should be (None, 41671, 43). I suspect it is related to the Conv1D layers, but I cannot find where it specifies the input shape after those layers.

How can I ensure that the input shape stays consistent while letting the number of rows vary? (I am cross-validating with my data)

I tried to change the dataset into a TensorFlow dataset instead of a Pandas one, but it did not detect the shape of the input at all when I did that.

Here is my model summary

```
Model: "model"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                   Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
 input_1 (InputLayer)           [(None, 41671, 43)]  0           []                               
                                                                                                  
 layer_normalization (LayerNorm  (None, 41671, 43)   86          ['input_1[0][0]']                
 alization)                                                                                       
                                                                                                  
 multi_head_attention (MultiHea  (None, 41671, 43)   179243      ['layer_normalization[0][0]',    
 dAttention)                                                      'layer_normalization[0][0]']    
                                                                                                  
 dropout (Dropout)              (None, 41671, 43)    0           ['multi_head_attention[0][0]']   
                                                                                                  
 tf.__operators__.add (TFOpLamb  (None, 41671, 43)   0           ['dropout[0][0]',                
 da)                                                              'input_1[0][0]']                
                                                                                                  
 layer_normalization_1 (LayerNo  (None, 41671, 43)   86          ['tf.__operators__.add[0][0]']   
 rmalization)                                                                                     
                                                                                                  
 conv1d (Conv1D)                (None, 41671, 4)     176         ['layer_normalization_1[0][0]']  
                                                                                                  
 dropout_1 (Dropout)            (None, 41671, 4)     0           ['conv1d[0][0]']                 
                                                                                                  
 conv1d_1 (Conv1D)              (None, 41671, 43)    215         ['dropout_1[0][0]']              
                                                                                                  
 tf.__operators__.add_1 (TFOpLa  (None, 41671, 43)   0           ['conv1d_1[0][0]',               
 mbda)                                                            'tf.__operators__.add[0][0]']   
                                                                                                  
 layer_normalization_2 (LayerNo  (None, 41671, 43)   86          ['tf.__operators__.add_1[0][0]'] 
 rmalization)                                                                                     
                                                                                                  
 multi_head_attention_1 (MultiH  (None, 41671, 43)   179243      ['layer_normalization_2[0][0]',  
 eadAttention)                                                    'layer_normalization_2[0][0]']  
                                                                                                  
 dropout_2 (Dropout)            (None, 41671, 43)    0           ['multi_head_attention_1[0][0]'] 
                                                                                                  
 tf.__operators__.add_2 (TFOpLa  (None, 41671, 43)   0           ['dropout_2[0][0]',              
 mbda)                                                            'tf.__operators__.add_1[0][0]'] 
                                                                                                  
 layer_normalization_3 (LayerNo  (None, 41671, 43)   86          ['tf.__operators__.add_2[0][0]'] 
 rmalization)                                                                                     
                                                                                                  
 conv1d_2 (Conv1D)              (None, 41671, 4)     176         ['layer_normalization_3[0][0]']  
                                                                                                  
 dropout_3 (Dropout)            (None, 41671, 4)     0           ['conv1d_2[0][0]']               
                                                                                                  
 conv1d_3 (Conv1D)              (None, 41671, 43)    215         ['dropout_3[0][0]']              
                                                                                                  
 tf.__operators__.add_3 (TFOpLa  (None, 41671, 43)   0           ['conv1d_3[0][0]',               
 mbda)                                                            'tf.__operators__.add_2[0][0]'] 
                                                                                                  
 layer_normalization_4 (LayerNo  (None, 41671, 43)   86          ['tf.__operators__.add_3[0][0]'] 
 rmalization)                                                                                     
                                                                                                  
 multi_head_attention_2 (MultiH  (None, 41671, 43)   179243      ['layer_normalization_4[0][0]',  
 eadAttention)                                                    'layer_normalization_4[0][0]']  
                                                                                                  
 dropout_4 (Dropout)            (None, 41671, 43)    0           ['multi_head_attention_2[0][0]'] 
                                                                                                  
 tf.__operators__.add_4 (TFOpLa  (None, 41671, 43)   0           ['dropout_4[0][0]',              
 mbda)                                                            'tf.__operators__.add_3[0][0]'] 
                                                                                                  
 layer_normalization_5 (LayerNo  (None, 41671, 43)   86          ['tf.__operators__.add_4[0][0]'] 
 rmalization)                                                                                     
                                                                                                  
 conv1d_4 (Conv1D)              (None, 41671, 4)     176         ['layer_normalization_5[0][0]']  
                                                                                                  
 dropout_5 (Dropout)            (None, 41671, 4)     0           ['conv1d_4[0][0]']               
                                                                                                  
 conv1d_5 (Conv1D)              (None, 41671, 43)    215         ['dropout_5[0][0]']              
                                                                                                  
 tf.__operators__.add_5 (TFOpLa  (None, 41671, 43)   0           ['conv1d_5[0][0]',               
 mbda)                                                            'tf.__operators__.add_4[0][0]'] 
                                                                                                  
 layer_normalization_6 (LayerNo  (None, 41671, 43)   86          ['tf.__operators__.add_5[0][0]'] 
 rmalization)                                                                                     
                                                                                                  
 multi_head_attention_3 (MultiH  (None, 41671, 43)   179243      ['layer_normalization_6[0][0]',  
 eadAttention)                                                    'layer_normalization_6[0][0]']  
                                                                                                  
 dropout_6 (Dropout)            (None, 41671, 43)    0           ['multi_head_attention_3[0][0]'] 
                                                                                                  
 tf.__operators__.add_6 (TFOpLa  (None, 41671, 43)   0           ['dropout_6[0][0]',              
 mbda)                                                            'tf.__operators__.add_5[0][0]'] 
                                                                                                  
 layer_normalization_7 (LayerNo  (None, 41671, 43)   86          ['tf.__operators__.add_6[0][0]'] 
 rmalization)                                                                                     
                                                                                                  
 conv1d_6 (Conv1D)              (None, 41671, 4)     176         ['layer_normalization_7[0][0]']  
                                                                                                  
 dropout_7 (Dropout)            (None, 41671, 4)     0           ['conv1d_6[0][0]']               
                                                                                                  
 conv1d_7 (Conv1D)              (None, 41671, 43)    215         ['dropout_7[0][0]']              
                                                                                                  
 tf.__operators__.add_7 (TFOpLa  (None, 41671, 43)   0           ['conv1d_7[0][0]',               
 mbda)                                                            'tf.__operators__.add_6[0][0]'] 
                                                                                                  
 global_average_pooling1d (Glob  (None, 41671)       0           ['tf.__operators__.add_7[0][0]'] 
 alAveragePooling1D)                                                                              
                                                                                                  
 dense (Dense)                  (None, 128)          5334016     ['global_average_pooling1d[0][0]'
                                                                 ]                                
                                                                                                  
 dropout_8 (Dropout)            (None, 128)          0           ['dense[0][0]']                  
                                                                                                  
 dense_1 (Dense)                (None, 1)            129         ['dropout_8[0][0]']              
                                                                                                  
==================================================================================================
Total params: 6,053,369
Trainable params: 6,053,369
Non-trainable params: 0
```

My training data shape is (41671, 43) and my label shape is (41671, 1).

Comment: Please provide your model.summary() and your train data and labels shapes.

Comment: I have added it into the original post.

Comment: The input shape does not contain the samples dimension, so this line input_shape=X_train.shape is incorrect.

Comment: When I create a tuple of three elements (say my batch size is 64), it then detects 4 dimensions instead of 3. For example, if I did (64, X_train.shape[0], X_train.shape[1]), it will interpret it as (None, None, 41671, 43) and raise that error.

Answer (score 0):

[Conv1D](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Conv1D#input-shape_1) accpets input shapes in `3+D tensor` with shape: (`batch_shape + (steps, input_dim)`), but your training dataset has a shape (41671, 43) which is 2D. So you need to expand dimension for the training dataset to make it compatible with the Conv1D layer.

You can do this using below code:

```
import numpy as np
#X_train = np.random.random_sample(size=(41671, 43))
X_train.shape #Output : (41671, 43)
X_train = np.expand_dims(X_train, axis=0) #or X_train = np.expand_dims(X_train, axis=-1)
X_train.shape
```

Output:

```
(1, 41671, 43)
```

and provide the `input_shape` to the model as below

```
input_shape=X_train.shape[1:]
```